# what's the neccessity of using an inner function to return to  the outer function?

Tags: javascript

What's the difference between these two functions?

```
function bind_1(f, o) {
    if (f.bind)
        return f.bind(o);
    else
        return function() { return f.apply(o. arguments); };
}

function bind_2(f, o) {
    if (f.bind)
        return f.bind(o);
    else
        return f.apply(o. arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vadim and Corbin are both mostly correct, but to add a little specificity and verbosity (I speak big words), bind_1 returns a function that will **always** call the given function (f) with the given arguments (o) set as the context - setting the context means that inside the function the *this* keyword will refer to the assigned context object. Whereas bind_2 will return **either**: the function (f) with the context (o), or return the result of calling the function (f) with the context (o).

Function.prototype.bind can also be used for partial function application. For instance, if you don't care to use the context inside a function you can provide functions with arguments already applied and therefore simplify subsequent calls:

```
// define a function which expects three arguments
function doSomething (person, action, message) {
    return person + " " + action + " " + message + ".";
}

var shortcut = doSomething.bind(null, "Joshua", "says");
// the call to bind here returns a function based on doSomething with some changes:
// 1. the context (_this_) is set to null
// 2. the arguments (person and action) are defined ("Joshua" and "says") and not changeable

// now we can use shortcut("Hello")
// instead of doSomething("Joshua", "says", "Hello")
shortcut("Hello"); // returns "Joshua says Hello."
```

The first argument passed to .apply(), .call(), or .bind() is changing the context of the function/method. The context is the value of the *this* keyword; thus, inside of the function the *this* value will be whatever is passed as the first argument. Here I was using *null* because in this case the function doesn't need a specific value for the context; and *null* is fewer characters than *undefined*, and feels better than some garbage value ("" - empty string, {} - empty object, etc.). So the remaining two variables are assigned as the first set of arguments to the function.

```
function exampleContext () {
    return this; // context of function execution
}

exampleContext(); // returns the global scope "window" (in the browser)

var exampleBind = exampleContext.bind(null);
exampleBind(); // returns "null"

var exampleBind = exampleContext.bind("Joshua");
exampleBind(); // returns "Joshua"

var exampleBind = exampleContext.bind({});
exampleBind(); // returns "Object {}""
```

Comment: +1 and now I feel silly.  I somehow completely neglected the `if (f.bind)` branch.

Comment: @kalisjoshua, yes, you did use a lot of big words resulted me more confuse even though you have tried to explain it clearly. Do you have way to do it at plain English and illustrate what you mean by examples? "return ... call function (f) with the given arguments (o) set as the context", "return function (f) with the context (o)", "return ... calling the function (f) with the context (o)" aren't they so similar to each other?

Comment: Regarding the partial function application, as the name implies, why do you need to still list 3 arguments by adding null object? In that case, shouldn't null refers to person, "Joshua" refers to action, and "says" refers to message?

Comment: @Corbin I almost did as well.

Comment: @kalisjoshua, do "return ... call function (f) with the given arguments (o) set as the context" same meaning as "return function (f) with the context (o)"? If they do, does that indicate one of bind_2's behaviors would be the same as bind_1's?

Comment: @user1386284, in a browser that supports Function.bind the two functions, bind_1 and bind_2, will perform indentically. However if there is not a definition for Function.bind the results will be very different. The else branch of each perform very differently; bind_1's else branch returns a new function that is not f, where bind_2's returns the result of calling the function f.

Comment: @kalisjoshua, then, under what kind of circumstances that we need to ONLY use the form of bind_1 since both will get the same result even though the returns are different but same result as bind_2?

Comment: The results are not entirely the same - as stated above, bind_2 will behave in an inconsistent way in non-standard browsers - bind_1 is probably what would be desired as it is going to be consistent, as far as I can interpret. However there does seem to be a typo in there since the reformatting of the original code: `f.apply(o. arguments);` should be `f.apply(o, arguments);` the comma is important.

Answer (score 1):

bind_1 returns a function that when called executes `f` with `o.arguments`.

bind_2 immediately executes `f` with `o.arguments`.

As for the 'necessity' of this, there is none that I can immediately see.  In some context in some person's code, it apparently has a purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases it's done to "attach" different context (`this` value) to the function.